# Logistic regression: Bias and cost function in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

The lectures Andrew Ng has said that

J= -1/m * sum (y*log(h(x))+(1-y)log(1-h(x)))

but in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners they state:

[image]

Why did they use this formula?

Comment: This seems to be about maths, not about Python.

Answer (score 1):

That is the binary vs the categorical approach. Andrew Ng cost function is binary crossentropy (or logloss), while the one used in the tensorflow tutorial is the categorical crossentropy. They use one-hot vector encoding to use this accross multiple categories. So even for 2 categories you have a label like this one: [0, 1].

In the binary case 0 is the label for the false case. This does not exist in the categorical case where only the 1 matters, because of the softmax classifier, where all your elements need to sum up to 1 anyways.

Comment: But which method is best used?

Comment: Depends on your data. You can use binary crossentropy only for 2 class problems, while the categorical one is used for multiclass problems.

Comment: @slava In TF, the according operation is called [`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).